# total size of group of files selected with 'find'

Tags: shell, scripting, find, grep, filesize

For instance, I have a large filesystem that is filling up faster than I expected. So I look for what's being added:

```
find /rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -type f -mtime -1 -ls | less
```

And I find, well, lots of stuff. Thousands of files of six-seven types. I can single out a type and count them:

```
find /rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "*offender1*" -mtime -1 -ls | wc -l
```

but what I'd really like is to be able to get the total size on disk of these files:

```
find /rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "*offender1*" -mtime -1 | howmuchspace
```

I'm open to a Perl one-liner for this, if someone's got one, but I'm not going to use any solution that involves a multi-line script, or File::Find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP specifically said:

> I'm open to a Perl one-liner for this, if someone's got one, but I'm
> not going to use any solution that involves a multi-line script, or
> File::Find.

...and there's none yet, here is the perl one-liner:

```
find . -name "*offender1*" | perl -lne '$total += -s $_; END { print $total }'
```

Answer (score 85):

The command [`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) tells you about disk usage. Example usage for your specific case:

```
find rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "offender1" -mtime -1 -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -n1
```

(Previously I wrote `du -hs`, but on my machine that appears to disregard `find`'s input and instead summarises the size of the cwd.)

Comment: Very nice. Although, remembering that brutal keyword to 'find' ("--files0-from=") may not actually be easier than remembering the 'awk' sequence.

Comment: Using `du` version 8.13 the following gives me the same result: `du -ch /rapidly_shrinking_drive/*offender1* | tail -n1`

Comment: My machine doesn't like the `--files0-from=` option. ;-/

Comment: An alternative that seems to work: `find rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "offender1" -mtime -1 -print0 | xargs -0 du -hc | tail -n1`

Comment: Note: The flag `--files0-from` argument in the above is _not_ a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 15):

Darn, Stephan202 is right.  I didn't think about du -s (summarize), so instead I used awk:

```
find rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "offender1" -mtime -1 | du | awk '{total+=$1} END{print total}'
```

I like the other answer better though, and it's almost certainly more efficient.

Comment: Alternative using -exec in the find :
`find rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "offender1" -mtime -1 -exec du {} \; | awk '{ total += $1 }END{ print total }'`

Comment: is it able to convert the final output number into more human readable format like 103M?

Comment: @zen you can use `numfmt` (parts of coreutils) and do something like `find rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "offender1" -mtime -1 | du | awk '{total+=$1} END{print total}' | numfmt --to=si`

Answer (score 9):

with GNU find,

```
 find /path -name "offender" -printf "%s\n" | awk '{t+=$1}END{print t}'
```

Comment: +1 for the explicit mention of GNU find. (To bad it is less portable that way).

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to promote jason's comment above to the status of answer, because I believe it's the most mnemonic (though not the most generic, if you really gotta have the file list specified by `find`):

```
$ du -hs *.nc
6.1M  foo.nc
280K  foo_region_N2O.nc
8.0K  foo_region_PS.nc
844K  foo_region_xyz.nc
844K  foo_region_z.nc
37M   ETOPO1_Ice_g_gmt4.grd_region_zS.nc
$ du -ch *.nc | tail -n 1
45M total
$ du -cb *.nc | tail -n 1
47033368  total
```

Answer (score 5):

Recently i faced the same(almost) problem and i came up with this solution.

```
find $path -type f -printf '%s '
```

It'll show files sizes in bytes, from `man find`:

```
-printf format
    True; print format on the standard output, interpreting `\' escapes and `%' directives.  Field widths and precisions can be spec‐
    ified as with the `printf' C function.  Please note that many of the fields are printed as %s rather than %d, and this  may  mean
    that  flags  don't  work as you might expect.  This also means that the `-' flag does work (it forces fields to be left-aligned).
    Unlike -print, -printf does not add a newline at the end of the string.
    ...
    %s  File's size in bytes.
    ...
```

And to get a total i used this:

```
echo $[ $(find $path -type f -printf %s+)0] #b
echo $[($(find $path -type f -printf %s+)0)/1024] #Kb
echo $[($(find $path -type f -printf %s+)0)/1024/1024] #Mb
echo $[($(find $path -type f -printf %s+)0)/1024/1024/1024] #Gb
```

Comment: Interesting and uses only `find` functionality! Nice! Can you please explain the `$[..]` syntax for echo ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă sure it's bash math syntax `echo $[1+1]` will print `2`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all this commands but no luck.
So I have found this one that gives me an answer:

```
find . -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{ s+=$5 } END { print s }'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use `ls -l` to find their size, then `awk` to extract the size:

```
find /rapidly_shrinking_drive/ -name "offender1" -mtime -1 | ls -l | awk '{print $5}' | sum
```

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, you need to use xargs