# Unix shell group files extensions by size

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

i want to group and sort files sizes by extensions in current and all subfolders

```
for i in `find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq `
do
   echo $i
done
```

got code which gets all files extensions in current and all subfolders

now i need to sum all files sizes  by those extensions and print them
Any ideas how this could be done?

example output:

```
sh (files sizes sum by sh extension)
pl (files sizes sum by pl extension)
c (files sizes sum by c extension)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a loop, so that you can provide a different extension every time and `find` just the files with that extension:

```
for extension in c php pl ...
do
   find . -type f -name "*.$extension" -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc
done
```

The sum is based on the answer in [total size of group of files selected with 'find'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134273/1983854).

In case you want the very specific output you mention in the question, you can store the last line and then print it together with the extension name:

```
for extension in c php pl ...
do
    sum=$(find . -type f -name "*.$extension" -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -1)
    echo "$extension ($sum)"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to name file extensions beforehand, the *stat(1)* program has a format option (-c) that can make tasks like this a bit easier, if you're on a system that includes it, and *xargs(1)* usually helps performance.

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -type f -name '*.*' -print0 |
  xargs -0 stat -c '%s %n' |
  sed 's/ .*\./ /' |
  awk '
    {
      sums[$2] += $1
    }
    END {
      for (key in sums) {
        printf "%s %d\n", key, sums[key]
      }
    }'
```

Comment: Mentioning performance and then piping `find`, `xargs`, `sed` and `awk` looks a bit contradictory.

Comment: Fair enough; many dimensions to performance. In the context of a shell script, I usually look to limit the number of processes invoked, and xargs is a nice way to do that. So, my stab at this gets a complete enumeration of all file extensions for the four commands you name, plus the number of times xargs invokes stat (system dependent - each invocation can likely handle about 128k worth of pathnames on a current system, so there's a benefit).

But it seems likely enough that hc would sum up file size info faster than awk...